# regex wont capture variables when nested in optional parenthesis

Tags: regex, perl

I am having trouble with this regex using nested parenthesis.

```
$regex ='^.*some_stuff\s+"([^"*)".*more_stuff\s+"([^"*)".*(even_more :"([^"]*)")?.*$'
```

I want an optional clause with a variable capture inside it (hence the nested parenthesis)
$1 and $2 are captured fine but I get the error:

```
Use of uninitialized vale $3 in concatenation (.) or string at perl_regex.pl
Use of uninitialized vale $4 in concatenation (.) or string at perl_regex.pl
```

for the last two captures. Interestingly when I remove the ? and take away the optional clause, It works fine but then I get a regex mismatch when I don't want one.

Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: Can you show some example input and expected output? Besides: regex isn't designed for nesting.

Comment: Looks like you'r missing a couple of closing brackets.

Answer (score 2):

The first `[` doesn't have a matching `]` before near the end of the entire expression.

Here is a breakdown:

```
^.*some_stuff\s+. # trivial
"([^"*)"          # double quote, start group, start character class ...
.*more_stuff\s+   # still in character class!
"([^"*)".*(even_more :
"([^"]*)          # end of character class, zero or more, close first group
")?.*$.           # ouch, extra )
```

Comment: Thanks.. that was actually a mistake typing on my part. It still doesn't seem to work for me. If I try this without nested parens: my $regex = '^.*?"blocked"\s+:\s+true.*?"clientip"\s+:\s+"([^"]*)".*?"containsadverts" : false.*?"destdomain" :\s+"([^"]*).*?("username" :\s+{ ")?([^"]*)?.*$'